# Scanner in Java

Tags: java, file-io

when I try to scan the folder Files it gives me an error saying access is denied. The folder contains txt files to scan through.

```
Scanner ScanningFile = new Scanner(new File("Files")); 
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Files (Access is denied)
```

Any Ideas ?

Comment: Your java process is not a previleged one to access the file

Comment: The (computer) user executing this Java app doesn't have sufficient rights to read that file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can't read a directory that way you need to use the [`File.listFiles()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28%29) methods

```
for(File textFile:new File("Files").listFiles()){
    Scanner ScanningFile = new Scanner(textFile);
    try{ 
        //...
    }finally{
        ScanningFile.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: assuming that "Files" is a folder

Comment: @MauricePerry it is indeed a folder, as is told in the question